# What´s the difference between using double quotes and single quotes in Excel

Tags: excel

I hope you are all well

I have a question.
When do I have to use single or double quotes in Excel? I have read somewhere that you use single quotes when you want to remove spaces?

For example, if one of my sheets is called Results lastyear and I put this name in my first tab (sheet1) in cell A1, when I am in my first tab and I want to use the Indirect function in cell B1, will both of the following functions work or do I have to use the single quote to remove the space between Results and lastyear?

```
=Counta(Indirect ("'"&A1&"'!"&"F:F)))
```

```
=Counta(Indirect (""&A1&"!"&"F:F))
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't put spaces in filenames or sheetnames as it causes too many issues, I do use the underscore though "_". I think it may be due to the variety of spaces that exist.

Comment: @SolarMike Sir, absolutely correct, even i follow the same, as you have mentioned, this is most recommended and it becomes easier to search as well!

Comment: You need the single quotes. The string you pass to INDIRECT needs to be the same as it would be in a direct formula reference, but adding single quotes does no harm even if it's not necessary, so it's safer to always use them.

Comment: as you correctly identified, its best to not have spaces in sheet names, ever. use camelCase or _ as Solar Mike suggests